# Python3 | Работа с сетью

Tags: python, python-3.x, wifi

Здравствуйте . Мне хотелось бы узнать как работать с **адаптером/роутером** напрямую через python3. В СИ можно через socket, в python` тоже есть socket, но вот статей как подключиться, как просканировать все ip адреса роутеров поблизости и т.д не понятно.

Почитал на счет этой темы, говорили использовать модуль wifi, глянул в исходный код, просто вызывает `sbin/iwlist` при помощи `subprocess`, это уже реализовано в `*nix` . По сути методом subprocess уже из готовых утилит которые работают с сетью. 
Напрямую я так понял нельзя вызывать, хотя наверное по любому можно, ведь **python сокеты** почти аналогичны **СИ сокетам**. Потому что python и написан на `СИ и TCL.`

Comment: в какой ОС хочешь это реализовать?

Comment: @eri os windows

Comment: @eri windows в приоритете, можно и на линукс.

Comment: с виндой не подскажу..

Comment: @eri а на линуксе?  Только не subprocess

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о сканировании сетей Wifi то socket тут не причём.

Для OS Windows можно получить скан сети через  WLAN API, подключив его по ctypes. Тут есть пример и такой же вопрос на ангийском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851233/how-can-i-retrieve-the-signal-strength-of-nearby-wireless-lan-networks-on-window

Для десктопного Linux мне кажется более правильным обратиться по dbus к NetworkManager. https://askubuntu.com/questions/137894/how-to-programmatically-get-a-list-of-wireless-ssids-in-range-from-networkmanage вот тут лаконичный ответ с кодом.

Если линукс не десктопный, то можно покапаться в http://docs.pyroute2.org/ - там есть всё для ручного управления сетью. Поищи как запустить `iw dev wlan0 scan` аналог через api.

Не питон, но можно прицепиться. http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtnetwork-index.html вот тут можно посмотреть. Особенно интересный раздел http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/bearer-management.html, но я не вникал.

Comment: А пример для python3 есть? работа с windows осуществлялась на питоне 2, у меня питон 3

Comment: портируй, исправь некоторые строки и всё запустится

Comment: точняк, заработало, но это очень муторное дело, особенно с таким кодом, других вариантов тоже нету?

Comment: посмотри в QT, там может найдешь

Comment: а чтоб оболочку приложения не создавать, а прямо в консоли все делать?

Comment: qt - это не только окошки, рисование окошек - это  10% его функций. можно  писать и консольные приложения.

Comment: добавил в ответ